# C++: Creating a vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I have a specific question on creating a vector of class objects. Having recently transitioned from Java, I am still foggy with this topic.

Let's say I have `class Foo {...}` and

```
Foo::Foo (string test) {
    string str = test;
}
```

I want to create a vector of *different* objects of class Foo. Is this possible, and if so, what is a simple way to do it? (in C++)

I was thinking of something like this:

```
vector<Foo> list;
for (int i = 1;i<10;i++) {
    Foo temp("test")
    list.push_back(temp);
}
```

but the problem is that I want to create *different* instances of the class, and not have them reference the same object.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the help and the kind comments. I realized that the obvious solution (the one you guys proposed) did not work in my program because I did not switch to the new version of C++. This question is solved.

Comment: std::vector<Foo> is what you're looking for.

Comment: pushback different objects? I don't entirely get the problem. you yourself posted the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for what is called a `vector`. A `vector` is similar to an `Array` but it is allowed to change its size during run time.

```
std::vector<Foo> v { Foo("A"),Foo("B"),Foo("C") };
```

Then you can access the objects by doing `v[0]`. If you wanted to add another object to the `vector` after initialization then you do `v.push_back(Foo("D"))`

Comment: Ah, I found why my program was not working, silly mistake. I forgot to change the compiler to C++11. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem can be solved by simply using the STL vector for your class.
Refer this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle{
    int length;
    int width;

    public: 
        Rectangle(int length, int width){
            this->length = length;
            this->width = width;    
        }


        int area(){
            return this->width * this->length;
        }
};

int main() {
    vector<Rectangle> v;
    v.push_back(Rectangle(1,2));
    v.push_back(Rectangle(3,4));

    cout << v[0].area()<<endl;
    cout << v[1].area()<<endl;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the STL vector library to achieve this.

```
std::vector<Foo> vectorOfObjects;

Foo newObject("A");
vectorOfObjects.push_back(newObject)
vectorOfObjects[0].doSomething();
```

Comment: I have a constructor parameter, so would it be: Foo newObject("stuff") for the second line? Also, I want to loop through pushing back objects. If I add a loop around the last three lines, would the items of the vector be referencing the same object, or different ones?

Comment: Each time you push back an item, they are different objects, even if their names are he same.

Comment: Ah, I thought they would reference the same object. thank you!